# Use the new "Thanks for submitting an edit" banner for suggested edits to tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When you've edited a tag wiki or excerpt, you see a banner:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/56237).

It is formatted in the same way as a regular blockquote, which is kinda confusing, especially when the blockquote is used in the wiki as well:

[image]

Can this be changed to use the new banner, like the following one?

[image]